Power BI Count number of Days cell is blank
I have a Power Bi report and I need to calculate the number of days a cell has been blank based of the delivery created on date. I have three columns in my data: delivery #, Created On, and Appointment Date. If there is no appointment date I want it to tell me how many days the cell has been blank since the date the delivery has been created. I am using a calendar table in Power Bi. Below is a sample of how I want it to work.
Sample
Need to calculate the number of days the cell is blank base on the delivery created date

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can create a column in your table to calculate the day difference between Created On date and today's date if there is no Appointed Date:

Days Blank = IF(ISBLANK('Table'[Appointed Date]) , DATEDIFF('Table'[Created on], TODAY(), DAY), BLANK()) 

